# SQL Server : DEFAULT int value

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a SQL problem - this is my table :

```
CREATE TABLE Compte
(
    Compte_Id             int not null IDENTITY (1, 1) primary key ,
    Compte_Nom            Varchar (25) ,
    Compte_Prenom         Varchar (25) ,
    Compte_Date_Naissance Date ,
    Compte_Rue            Varchar (25) ,
    Compte_Telephone      Varchar (25) ,
    Compte_Mail           Varchar (25) ,
    Compte_Pseudo         Varchar (25) ,
    Compte_MotDePasse     Varchar (25) ,
    Compte_Compte_Ogrine  Int DEFAULT 0,
    Compte_Argent_reel Int DEFAULT 0,
)
```

I want to use this table in my C# program, so my insert will look like that:

```
INSERT INTO Compte ([Compte_Id], [Compte_Nom], [Compte_Prenom],
                    [Compte_Date_Naissance], [Compte_Rue], 
                    [Compte_Telephone], [Compte_Mail], [Compte_Pseudo],
                    [Compte_MotDePasse], [Compte_Compte_Ogrine],[Compte_Argent_reel])
VALUES ('ui', 'ui', '1996-06-25', 'ui', '09', 'ui', 'ui', 'ui')
```

but if I put this on my SQL Server, it doesn't work !

Error message :

> Msg 109, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause.
>
> The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.

Comment: Which part of "There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause" did you not understand?

Comment: you can't (generally) insert an identity field yourself so it is another problem that you include [Compte_Id] in your list of columns to insert.

Comment: Always Google, before posting here

Answer (score 5):

**'There are *more columns* in the INSERT statement *than values* specified in the VALUES clause'**

*If* a column name is specified *then* a value *must* be supplied for that column.

The 'fix' is to *remove* the columns names that are to have the default assigned; this includes any identity column as well.

```sql
INSERT INTO Compte (
  -- Don't include this, identity column! [Compte_Id]
   [Compte_Nom]
  ,[Compte_Prenom]
  ,[Compte_Date_Naissance]
  ,[Compte_Rue]
  ,[Compte_Telephone]
  ,[Compte_Mail]
  ,[Compte_Pseudo]
  ,[Compte_MotDePasse])
  -- Don't specify, assume default value! ,[Compte_Compte_Ogrine]
  -- Don't specify, assume default value! ,[Compte_Argent_reel])
  VALUES
  ('ui','ui','1996-06-25','ui','09','ui','ui','ui')
```

Comment: Oh ok ! I know what u mean, i removed compte_id too , and it worked ! Thanx a lot !

Comment: @sok Then please mark the response as the answer - that is how SO works for people looking for actual answers to problems..

Answer (score 2):

As the message says *"There are more columns"*, you have 11 columns in your insert, but 8 values only.

Do not include a `identity` column in `insert` statement (Compte_Id)

Comment: The OP also includes two additional "default" fields at the end, without specifying a value.

Comment: you're right @user2864740, good pointed

Answer (score 1):

The number of columns in the INSERT must match the number of columns in the VALUES.
you have 11 columns in the INSERT and 8 in the VALUES.

Also, Compte_Id is an identity column so you don't have to specify a value for it in the insert statement because SQL Server will automatically set a value for it.

Remove [Compte_Id], [Compte_Compte_Ogrine] and [Compte_Argent_reel] in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Now it work correctly.

```
INSERT INTO Compte ([Compte_Nom], [Compte_Prenom],
                [Compte_Date_Naissance], [Compte_Rue], 
                [Compte_Telephone], [Compte_Mail], [Compte_Pseudo],
                [Compte_MotDePasse])
VALUES ('ui', 'ui', '1996-06-25', 'ui', '09', 'ui', 'ui', 'ui')`
```